# Why is this buffer initialized in the following manner?

Tags: java, initialization, declaration

I could see the following initialization in `javax.crypto.CipherInputStream` (Line 77)

```
private byte[] ibuffer = new byte['Ȁ'];
```

What does `Ȁ` mean, and why is the buffer initialised in this way?

Comment: what decompiler do you use ?  that must be `private byte[] ibuffer = new byte[512];`

Comment: Where did you read this? The original source says 512, which is 'Ȁ' when expressed as `char`.

Comment: I'm using jad decompiler @Polygnome. Sorry I didn't looked up the original source.

Comment: Then this is probably a problem with the decompiler, which interprets the bytecode in a funny way. while its certainly *possible*to write it that way (char gets cast to int anyways), no sane programmer would ever do that (except when trying to golf an answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this source code : [javax/crypto/CipherInputStream.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/crypto/CipherInputStream.java), this array is initialized with

```
 /* the buffer holding data that have been read in from the
  underlying stream, but have not been processed by the cipher
  engine. the size 512 bytes is somewhat randomly chosen */

 private byte[] ibuffer = new byte[512];
```

512 is the integer value of character `'Ȁ'`, so it is the same initialization.

Try : `System.out.println((char) 512);`

Answer (score 2):

It's a `char` converted to `int`. The value is 512

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with decompilers, they only look at the bytecode and try to *reconstruct* the source.

If you look at the original source in [javax.crypto.CipherInputStream (Line 77)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/crypto/CipherInputStream.java#77), you will see that the line is originally

```
 private byte[] ibuffer = new byte[512];
```

`'Ȁ'` is of the type `char`, and if you cast it to `int`, it has the value of 512. Your decompiler reconstructed one possible way to generate that bytecode - but in this case, no sane programmer would write it that way (except when golfing or deliberately obfuscating the code).